# Sequential color for tm_bubbles()

Tags: r

I want to give the different dot size a sequential color, but it doesn't function

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
example(st_read)

tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74")+tm_scale_bar() + tm_bubbles(size="SID79",scale=0.5,style="quantile",palette="Reds")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand if this is what you mean, but sample code below. The size of the dot and its color depends on the variable `SID79`. However, the palette you choose makes red dots on a red background. It is illegible.

```r
library(tmap)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
example(st_read)
#> 
#> (...)

tm_shape(nc)+
  tm_fill("NWBIR74")+
  tm_scale_bar()+
  tm_bubbles(size="SID79", scale=0.5, style="quantile", col = "SID79", palette="Reds")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I am supplementing with an answer to an additional question. It is of course possible to disable the legend for the color scale. To make it readable, I enlarged `tm_bubbles` and changed the fill color to green.

```r
library(tmap)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
example(st_read)
#> 
#> (...)

tm_shape(nc)+
  tm_fill("NWBIR74")+
  tm_scale_bar()+
  tm_bubbles(size="SID79", scale=2, style="quantile", col = "SID79", palette="Greens", legend.col.show = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: okay but how can you remove the second legend of SID79'

Comment: I have supplemented the code with this issue.